# What Should i do when i am getting null values after using .getoptions() for select class in java selenium

Tags: selenium

This is the website I am practicing on
https://rahulshettyacademy.com/dropdownsPractise/

This is my code:

```
    WebElement origin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1\"]"));
    Select ori = new Select(origin);
    List<WebElement> oriui = ori.getOptions();
    int size = oriui.size();
    for (int i =0; i < size ; i++) {
        String options = oriui.get(i).getText();
        System.out.println(options);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's beautify your code first. https://codebeautify.org/javaviewer

```
WebElement origin = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1 "]"));
Select ori = new Select(origin);
List oriui = ori.getOptions();
int size = oriui.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  String options = oriui.get(i).getText();
  System.out.println(options);
```

First, to get the select element properly, pass the XPath as a `String`. Use the single quote or escape character as the element ID in the xpath also a nested String in this case.

Be like..

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1']"));`

Alternatively you can use `By.id` if you are calling it by ID only.

`driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1"));`

```
public void Test() throws Exception {
        String URL = "https://rahulshettyacademy.com/dropdownsPractise/";
        driver.get(URL);
        
        WebElement origin = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_ddl_originStation1"));
        Select ori = new Select(origin);
        List<WebElement> oriui = ori.getOptions();
        for(WebElement ele : oriui) {
            System.out.println(ele.getAttribute("text"));

        }
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
Departure City
Adampur (AIP)
Ahmedabad (AMD)
Amritsar (ATQ)
......
Srinagar (SXR)
Vijayawada (VGA)
Vishakhapatnam (VTZ)
```